# private key distribution techniques?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, private-key

I made a chat application with java rmi client server. For the security of my messages using the RSA algorithm, but my difficulty in distributing the private key into the opponent's chat. Perhaps from my friends there who can help how to distribute a private key to the opponent so that he can decrypt the chat messages sent.

Comment: Why would you want to distribute the private key there? The whole idea is to keep the private key, well *private*

Comment: Indeed.  You should be encrypting outgoing messages with the friend's _public_ key, so only they can decrypt it with their private key.

Comment: He talks about *a* private key. Not his or his friends. This implies that he means a symmetric key.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you never distribute private key, whilst public key can be publicly (duh!) available. You encrypt your message using the public key of the person on the second side of the chat, and they use their private key to decrypt it. You can send your public key using plaintext, via e-mail or publish it on your website so others can encrypt their messages to you with it.

To make your life easier invest in using e.g. [ssl](/questions/tagged/ssl) - which is much faster since after establishing secure channel using asymmetric encryption it exchanges symmetric session keys and uses much faster symmetric encryption.

Actually, distributing of a public key might be an issue as well. If your opponent can also modify the transmission (as opposed to only listening to your transmission channel) he/she can send bogus public key of yours. That's why public keys (e.g. on website) need to be signed by the chain of trusted authorities (whose public keys are hard-coded in the web browser).

Comment: Public keys needs to be trusted, but trusted authorities are only one way to accomplish that (web of trust, out of band communication etc).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is an asymmetric scheme to transfer the info. With asymmetric encryption, even if someone is listening in, they can't know what they key is. You can encrypt the message using this, but generally you use it to encrypt a symmetric key and then use that from there on.

Have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) for more information about the background.

As for how to do it in your code, I would suggest googling something along the lines of "java public key library".

Comment: He's already using an asymmetric scheme since he's talking about private keys. He even has RSA as a tag..

Comment: @Voo, just because the tag and the name is used, it doesn't mean he understands the ideas? If he did this question would be unnecessary?

Comment: If that was the purpose of the post fine. Starting the post with `you need to use an asymmetric scheme` when he's already using RSA, may be a bit confusing not only to the poster but also other readers ;)

Comment: @Voo RSA tag was added by Thomasz, but RSA was already in the question

Answer (score 0):

RSA is a public key cryptography where your clients have a public key and you have a private key using which you decrypt the message that is the message is encryprted using clients public key and decrypted using your private key.
you can check this out http://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html
it very much explains in detail that how it works.
this PPT explains how it can be implemented in java
[www.cs.cityu.edu.hk/~cs4288/Java/RSA.doc](http://www.cs.cityu.edu.hk/%7Ecs4288/Java/RSA.doc)
its really helpful.

Hope it helps!!